# Javascript Objects properties not getting added

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, mongoose

I have a couple of commands in my server side mongoose code, but i don't know why I am not able to add more properties to this data object on the server side, whereas I am able to do the same in the chrome console without any problems

```
var data = {};
        data = noteData;
        data.uploader = req.user.username;
        console.log(data.uploader);
        console.log(req.user.username);
        data.actualFileName = actualFileName;
        console.log(data.actualFileName);
        console.log(actualFileName);
        data.storedFileName = storedFileName;
        console.log(data.storedFileName);
        console.log(req.storedFileName);
        console.log(data);
```

the noteData has the following values -

```
{"title":"1","subject":"2","author":"3","department":"CSE","college":"MSRIT","description":"45","details":"5","tags":["6"]}
```

and the console output for the above code fragment is  -

```
undefined
harshitladdha93@gmail.com
undefined
[ 'EIPR.odt', 'EIPR.docx' ]
undefined
undefined
{"title":"1","subject":"2","author":"3","department":"CSE","college":"MSRIT","description":"45","details":"5","tags":["6"]}
```

What else should i try to debug this error or what other information should i provide?

Answer (score 1):

when you say data = noteData - it is now the same type as noteData... so if noteData.property does not exist, data's property will not exist.

Comment: so if i skip that part and write noteData.uploader = value; and so on then it should work right? but it is not apparently. I did try both the ways in chrome console and both worked fine, doesn't matter if i use data = noteData

Comment: it looks like in the string you shared for noteData's value, there is no value for "uploader"... so it wont work.  if noteData is an object that you instantiated, and if you set noteData.uploader to something, then yes it will work.  try data.base = noteData... then continue with the rest of your code... then data.base will hold the string and also the rest of the properties will set properly

Comment: because data is a separate instance of the object.  so by setting the value to data, it does nothing to noteData.  if you want to set noteData as an object of type data, use something like http://barnescode.com/f/ex.txt .. otherwise, you need to explicitly set noteData.uploader

Answer (score 1):

**Try this method**, if it doesn't work, show us your mongoose code.

```
var data = {};
data = noteData;

data['uploader'] = 'USER_NAME';
console.log(data.uploader);
data['actualFileName'] = 'FILE_NAME';
console.log(data.actualFileName);
data['toredFileName'] = 'STORE_FILENAME';
console.log(data.storedFileName);
console.log(data);

Object {title: "1", subject: "2", author: "3", department: "CSE", college: "MSRIT"…}
actualFileName: "FILE_NAME"
author: "3"
college: "MSRIT"
department: "CSE"
description: "45"
details: "5"
subject: "2"
tags: Array[1]
title: "1"
toredFileName: "STORE_FILENAME"
uploader: "USER_NAME"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: I just changed the busboy method to receive the fields, and it received the results as expected, I think i mistook the behavior of busboy in receiving or sending data along with files. Anyways, thanks for the time